# Android Studio crashes intermittently with com.intellij.util.DeprecatedMethodException

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, intermittent

I have recently installed Android Studio on my new setup. However, it keeps on crashing unexpectedly at random times, without warning.

The same exception keeps happening during the crash:

```
2022-01-13 15:23:06,066 [  85372]   WARN - util.DeprecatedMethodException - This method in 'com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.LineMarkerInfo' is deprecated and going to be removed soon. Please use LineMarkerInfo(T, TextRange, Icon, Function, GutterIconNavigationHandler, Alignment, Supplier) instead 
com.intellij.util.DeprecatedMethodException: This method in 'com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.LineMarkerInfo' is deprecated and going to be removed soon. Please use LineMarkerInfo(T, TextRange, Icon, Function, GutterIconNavigationHandler, Alignment, Supplier) instead
    at com.intellij.util.DeprecatedMethodException.report(DeprecatedMethodException.java:28)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.LineMarkerInfo.<init>(LineMarkerInfo.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinSuspendCallLineMarkerProvider$SuspendCallMarkerInfo.<init>(KotlinSuspendCallLineMarkerProvider.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinSuspendCallLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(KotlinSuspendCallLineMarkerProvider.kt:77)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:182)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$3(LineMarkersPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:81)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:78)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$1(PassExecutorService.java:400)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1146)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:393)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:392)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:189)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:366)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:188)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

My machine is running on Ubuntu 21.10, and the Android Studio version is 2020.3.1 Patch 2, installed from `snap`(although the same problem happened when installed from the official website).

Thank you!

Comment: I would suspect that the used snap is defect. I would recommend to install the official version without snap (at the moment AS 2020.3.1. Patch 4).

Comment: Thank you, I'll go try that out. But I remember also installing from the Android Developer website on the same machine but getting the same error.